# How does the back EMF from the inductor interact with the rest of the circuit?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

Suppose I have the following simple circuit with a 5V source, a 1kΩ resistor, and a 1H inductor. A switch prevents any current from flowing.

[image]

Initially, the voltage propagates through the resistor so that there is 5V at one terminal of the switch. There is no voltage drop across the resistor and thus no current (or I guess there's no current and therefore no voltage drop? It's like a chicken vs egg scenario and I'm not sure which comes first).

Anyways, when the switch connects, [the circuit starts doing its thing](https://i.imgur.com/PKpgNmm.mp4) and we get the transient voltage (green line) and current (yellow line) current curves that are imprinted on my brain from undergrad:

[image]

**Here's a simplified version of what they taught me in undergrad:** An instant after the switch closes, the entire 5 volts drops across the inductor and not the resistor. The current rises but slowly instead of instantaneously, because we were taught inductors don't like changes in current. As this happens, the voltage drop across the resistor starts falling. Now there's less voltage to go around, so the voltage drop across the inductor decreases. Finally, at steady state (infinitely far in the future), there's no voltage drop across the inductor; it's a short. Thus, we're left with a simple single-resistor circuit and Ohm's Law says the current will slowly tend towards 5V/1kΩ = 5mA.

This is enough for practical analysis. However, some things confuse me from a physics standpoint...

So you start out with Faraday's Law, $v(t) = -d\Phi_B(t)/dt$. If you assume the inductor is a solenoid, you can easily get what $\Phi_B$ is by finding the magnetic field *produced* by the solenoid and then deriving w.r.t. time $t$. Eventually you end up with

$$v(t)=-L\frac{di}{dt}$$

This $v(t)$ is **back EMF** and is the voltage drop across the inductor. According to the formula says that this voltage depends on the changing current. If the current starts to increase from 0mA, then there will be an EMF pointing the other way. To try and oppose that change.

**Several things confuse me:** How is the current actually "opposed"? The current keeps increasing the entire time, in fact this rate of increase is at its highest as soon as the switch closes. Plus, the voltage drop is positive just like the resistor's, I would have thought it would point the other way, i.e. try to push the current back into the battery.

**My Main Question:** The nanosecond the switch closes, there's is 5V EMF from the battery and the electrons have yet to be accelerated to form a current. As the battery starts accelerating them, what happens with the inductor?

Comment: Are you asking about transmission line effects and/or displacement current?

Comment: @DKNguyen nah my confusion is more fundamental. The voltage drop across an inductor is the back emf derived via Faraday's Law. But what is it pushing against? The battery? Then why is the voltage pointed the other way? 

Not sure if displacement current is the thing that bridges my understanding. I thought it was mostly important for capacitors?

Comment: I always thought of it as energy was being removed from circulation by the inductor and placed into the magnetic field to build it. Similar to how a resistor removes energy and makes a voltage drop, except it just burns it off as heat rather than stored in a magnetic field.

Comment: @DKNguyen ah but the tricky thing for me is that this current takes energy and gives it to magnetic fields but those magnetic fields turn around and affect those same currents. There's this self-relationship (I guess that's why they call it self-inductance) and I'm not sure why it plays out how the equations tell us. Those equations are a good way to arrive at answers but I'm confused about the actual mechanics that get us there.

Comment: It's like how you can use KE and PE in mechanics to derive how fast a pendulum will be swinging at the bottom after you you let it go from the top, but it doesn't tell me what causes the pendulum to get to that state. For that you need Newton's Laws and whatnot. You'd say there's a component of gravity that acts perpendicular to the rope and gives the ball velocity.

Comment: To me that sounds like how when you push on a block it pushes back on you. You'll have to wait for someone else.

Comment: This question is very unfocused. You go over a rather broad litany of things that confuse you. Please narrow it down to one clear central question.

Comment: @Dale made some edits, is it still too unfocused?

Comment: That is much better. Thanks.